# In the HTML code to embed a YouTube video, what does accelerometer, gyroscope, and picture-in-picture do?

Tags: html, youtube

Once you finish uploading a video on Youtube, there is suggested embedding HTML code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UF8uR6Z6KLc" frameborder="0" 
 allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What exactly does the `accelerometer`, `gyroscope`, and `picture-in-picture` do?

Answer (score 12):

According to YouTube Help section:

**Picture in Picture** - [Read Here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7552722?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Android)
Allows you to watch YouTube videos while using other apps on your mobile device.

**Gyroscope & Accelerometer**

This usually refers to when a user rotates or moves their device around, so I'm guessing this would be for when someone embeds a Virtual Reality or 360degree video?

Comment: you said "Gyroscope & Accelerometer:

This usually refers to when a user rotates or moves their device around" I think when you rotate your phone, putting the video on the corresponding view should be still considered "upright". It'd be weird if the code says when the user rotates the phone, don't rotate the video and just let the user rotate the head

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean unfortunately but if you watch a few of the VR or 360 videos and move your phone around I think it'll help to understand what I mean.

Comment: ok, if it is VR, that makes sense. At first I thought you mean just rotating it and what I meant was, that should be agnostic to the embedding code... the device can rotate or not rotate and the embedding code should not be concerned about it